# ASPxGridView inline EditForm text field auto fill

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have ASPxGridView on my WebForm. What I want to do is to add fill the UserID automatically if user has entered **FirstName** and **LastName**. Image is attached.

[image]

For example, if **FirstName** = "Faizan" and **LastName** = "Mubasher" then **UserID** must be auto filled with value "Faizan.Mubasher". How to achieve it on client side.

Here is my .aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="main-margin">
            <div>
                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True" Theme="DevEx" CssClass="col-md-12" 
                    ClientInstanceName="grid"
                    OnDataBinding="ASPxGridView1_DataBinding" 
                    OnRowUpdating="ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating"
                    OnRowInserting="ASPxGridView1_RowInserting"
                    OnRowDeleting="ASPxGridView1_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowValidating="ASPxGridView1_RowValidating"
                    OnStartRowEditing="ASPxGridView1_StartRowEditing"
                    OnCustomButtonCallback="ASPxGridView1_CustomButtonCallback"
                    >
                        <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                            <EditButton Visible="True"/>
                            <NewButton Visible="True"/>
                            <ClearFilterButton Visible="True">
                            </ClearFilterButton>
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="1">
                            <CustomButtons>
                                <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="cbSendEmail" Text="Send Email" >
                                </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                            </CustomButtons>
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Email" VisibleIndex="2" Name="Email"> 
                        <EditFormSettings/>
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="True"/>
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="FirstName" VisibleIndex="3" Name="FirstName">
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
                            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="LastName" VisibleIndex="4" Name="LastName" >
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="UserID" VisibleIndex="5" Name="UserID" >
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Password" VisibleIndex="6" Name="Password" >
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="RetryCount" VisibleIndex="7" Name="RetryCount">
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" />
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False"/>
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="MaxRetryCount" VisibleIndex="8" Name="MaxRetryCount" >
                            <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="9">
                            <CustomButtons>
                                <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="cbBlockAccount" Text="Block Account">
                                </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                            </CustomButtons>
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="10" ButtonType="Button">
                            <DeleteButton Visible="True" />
                        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
                        <SettingsText ConfirmDelete="Confirm Delete" />
                        <SettingsPopup>
                            <EditForm Width="600" />
                        </SettingsPopup>
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
            </div> 
        </form>
```

Comment: try this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103740/force-server-textchanged-event-from-javascript

Comment: Not relevant. Need to dig more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spending plenty of time and playing with it, we need to add couple of *Javascript* functions and modify specific GridView's **Data Columns**.

First of all, change `<dx:GridViewDataColumn` with `<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn` and then add following it's child node:

```
    <PropertiesTextEdit ClientInstanceName="firstname">
        <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="onFirstNameChanged" />
    </PropertiesTextEdit>
```

Here **ClientSideEvents** property tag is used to raise an event on client side using *Javascript*. Similarly, modify other required Data Columns. For example, I modified three DataColumns of **FieldNames**, *FirstName*, *LastName* and *UserID*.

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FirstName" VisibleIndex="3" Name="FirstName" SortOrder="None">
     <PropertiesTextEdit ClientInstanceName="firstname">
          <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="onFirstNameChanged" />
     </PropertiesTextEdit>
     <Settings AllowAutoFilter="True" />
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LastName" VisibleIndex="4" Name="LastName">
     <PropertiesTextEdit ClientInstanceName="lastname">
           ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="onLastNameChanged" />
     </PropertiesTextEdit>
     <Settings AllowAutoFilter="True" />
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UserID" VisibleIndex="5" Name="UserID" ReadOnly="true">
     <PropertiesTextEdit ClientInstanceName="uid"></PropertiesTextEdit>
     <Settings AllowAutoFilter="True" />
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Note that I haven't added

Note that I haven't added **ValueChanged** client side event for DataColumn **UserID** because it is not required.

Lastly, add *Javascript* events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fName
    var lName
    function onFirstNameChanged(s, e) {
        fName = s.GetValue();
    };
    function onLastNameChanged(s, e) {
        lName = s.GetValue();
        grid.GetEditor("UserID").SetValue(fName + "." + lName);
    };
</script>
```

This Javascript is pretty much simple. **grid** is the *ClientInstanceName* of ASPxGridView1. This instance name is used to access grid's properties in Javascript and provide useful functions at client side. So, I got **UserID** field and set its value as soon as user enters last name in *LastName* field and this worked for me.

Hint taken from: [How to use Javascript on AspxGridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507663/how-to-use-javascript-on-aspxgridview)